# Nonlinear regression with a discrete independent variable

Tags: r, math, statistics, non-linear-regression

It turns out that I have two variables that do not satisfy the assumption of linearity. The dependent variable is continuous and the independent variable is numeric and discrete. Here the residual plot and a box and whisker plot:
[image]
[image]
Therefore, I can not use a linear regression.
I've tried unsuccessfully to linearize the relationship between the variables by transforming the data (by doing log(y); log(x); sqrt(y); etc...). I did not find any transformation that satisfactorily increased the linearity.
Thus, I have ended up trying to fit non-linear functions to my data (It is a totally unknown field for me, and I have not been able to find much information on the internet).
I would therefore like to know if I am taking the correct steps for my nonlinear analysis:

1) First thing I did was to choose a quadratic polynomial

```
y = a + (b*x) + c*(x^2)
```

Here is my first doubt (what function to use?) since I know there are infinitely many different functions that could describe the same line.

2) Second thing I did was to estimate the parameters by using the non-linear least squares approach (function nls in R) which basically approximate the non-linear function using a linear one and iteratively try to find the best parameter values:

```
m <- nls(y ~ a + (b*x) + c*(x^2), start= list(a = 2, b = 1, c=1))
```

To choose the initial values (start) for the parameters I tried to choose initial values that are close to the expected final solution. Although I have found that even if I change the initial values, the final result remains the same. Here are the estimated values for the parameters after the non-linear least squares approach:

> ```
> Nonlinear regression model
>   model: y ~ a + (b * x) + c * (x^2)
>    data: parent.frame()
>       a       b       c 
>  2.1296 -0.9395 -1.1754 
>  residual sum-of-squares: 27615
>
> Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
> Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.58e-08
> ```

3) Finally, I check the results by doing `summary(m)`:

> ```
> Formula: y ~ a + (b * x) + c * (x^2)
>
> Parameters:
>    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
> a  2.129555   0.003976  535.56   <2e-16 ***
> b -0.939467   0.018500  -50.78   <2e-16 ***
> c -1.175413   0.017818  -65.97   <2e-16 ***
> ---
> Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
>
> Residual standard error: 0.5114 on 105597 degrees of freedom
>
> Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
> Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.58e-08
> ```

I also run a little piece of code to get some model evaluation:

```
RSS <- sum(residuals(m)^2)
TSS <- sum((y - mean(y))^2)
R.square <- 1 - (RSS/TSS)
```

Result:

> ```
> R.square 
> 0.6365729
> ```

I do not know if my procedure was orthodox. I would like to know if I have taken the right steps.
I also appreciate some clue to know what is the best way to interpret the stats and report these results.

Comment: Please define what you consider the assumption of linearity.

Comment: Sure. Here. Page 12: http://bodowinter.com/tutorial/bw_LME_tutorial1.pdf

Comment: It's not clear from your comment you fully appreciate what linearity assumption really is. Perhaps consult a local statistician.

Comment: Looks like you describe linearity as using a `y ~ x` formula. Even if it doesn't seem a good approach I'd recommend you first test it (model comparison) before you decide... But, most importantly when you validate your model (or models in order to compare) use some form of cross-validation, because it looks like you build and validate on same data and that might lead to overfitting (especially if you try polynomial of a higher order). In case you ask "why model comparison?" the question(s) for you is "why stop at quadratic polynomial? Why not cubic? Why not a completely different model?"

Comment: What do you mean by validate on same data? I do not understand. My definition of the linearity assumption is of course based in the relationship between dependent and independent variables. The relationship between the two variables must be linear. And the linearity assumption can be tested with scatter plots or residual plots. In this case, I observe a violation of the linearity assumption. Which other approach do you suggest to test the linearity assumption?

Comment: I'm talking about validating your model. Try to find some info on overfitting and why cross-validation produces more robust (non biased) metrics. A simple example of cross validation is to randomly split your dataset to a train and a test set and use one for training/building the model and the other one as a test/validation set.

Answer (score 2):

The point of linear regression is to approximate your nonlinear data with a line, not start with linear data. Looking at your red dots above it looks like you need a quadratic regression. The equations you can program can be found over at math.stackexchange. [Quadratic Regression equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267865/equations-for-quadratic-regression)

Comment: But the relationship between your variables should be linear (it's one of the fourth assumptions to run linear regressions), right? I've used a quadratic polynomial and I've estimated the parameters by using the non-linear least squares approach (function nls in R). Is this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, using a polynomial **is** a case of linear regression, since linear is referred to the dependence of the fit parameter and not to the independent variable. The form you have to use is up to you. However, your data seem to lie to zero when x grows, so I wouldn't use a polynomial but something like a long-tailed distribution. Then, it is OK if your final estimate of the parameters does not depend on the initial guess (maybe I'm wrong, but I remember that this should be always true in the case of linear regression, while in with non-linear cases there may be many minima in the sum of squared residuals). Finally, be careful with the R^2: it must be used **only** in the case of a linear regression (and this is your case), but it is completely useless and meaningless if you perform a non-linear fit.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What do you mean when you say "using a polynomial is a case of linear regression". I thought that using polynomials was a common way to fit a nonlinear relationship between variables: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression

Comment: Even fitting a quadratic or any polynomial, say ax^2+bx+c, we are looking for a, b, and c which do not have any powers. It is a linear system of equations that are solved for.

Comment: @pyring as said also in the comments above, _linear_ is referred to the dependence of the parameters and **not** to the functional form of the independent variable. So, for a generic polynomial, e.g. a+b*x+c*x^2+d*x^3... you have a,b,c,d.. appearing linearly in the function, so it is linear (and hence linear are the equations that must be solved to minimize the sum of square residuals)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In the example I showed, I'm using a polynomial to fit the cloud of data points (the relathionship between variables, which is not linear). Do you think is the correct way to proceed? Giving my data, from your comment above, maybe it would be better to use another function, right? I appreciate suggestions.

Comment: You're welcome! Usually a good way to proceed is to try to upgrade your model step by step keeping it as simple as possible, and a quadratic dependence could be a good attempt. If not, you can try to add more powers and see what happens until you get a satisfying description of your data. In the answer above I suggested you a long-tailed distribution because of it seems that data start to lie down to zero (but may be only a fluctuation), and this can be the case if your _y_ must assume only positive values (if you use a parabola, your fit will go down to negative values).

Comment: Great. Well, after running the regression using a quadratic polynomial I get R2=0.6366, and with a cubic polynimial R2=0.6391 (so, for simplicity, I guess that it makes sense to keep the quadratic one -although, as you suggested, I'm considering using a long-tailed function-). My question now is, how should I report effect sizes of my independent variable when interpreting the results of the polynomial regression? Any suggestion?

Comment: Yep, I would made the same insight from these values of R^2 (however, I'm not a R user so I do not know how it is computed and so on; sure, it seems to be stable so lets keep only the quadratic term). As regards the second question, are you referring to the interpretation of the best fit parameters?

Comment: Exactly. Because in a prototypical linear regression (y = b0 + b1*x) the way to read the output of x (our predictor effect or effect size) is quite straightforward: "for every increase of x by 1, the effect of x on y is b1". However, for the quadratic regression, the interpretation of the effect of x on y seems to be a bit more complicated. How could I report (read, explain) the effect of my independent variable in an elegant way? I appreciate your comments.

Comment: Glad to help you! With a polynomial fit you just have to refer to the transformed data, since the effect follows a certain non-linear function of your independent variable. So, for example, with a fit y=a-b*x^2 I would just rephrase saying "for an increase of x, y decreases proportionally to the square of x^2". Actually, it is not this interpretation to be complicated, but just that in the linear case to be extremely simple (and we are also lucky since your model fits a parabola... do you imagine with more complicated non-linear functions?)

Comment: Thanks! In fact, using a prototypical linear regression (y = b0 + b1*x) I get R2=0.6212. Giving my data, this R2 is almost the same when using a quadratic regression. However, in the case of the polynomial regression the assumption of linearity is not a requirement, right? On the other hand, I understand how you explain y=a-b*x^2, but I still have doubts about how could I read effect sizes in y = a -  b*x - c*x^2. Maybe I should open a new question :)